# I can't get the profile name and pic with a query search from firebase database in Android Studio. App stops working. Any fix?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm copying the entire activity below, findfriendsactivity.java to search and query name, profile and pic from firebase database in Android Studio after I run the app. Apps stops working when I type and search a name. App worked fine before this activity. How can I fix this?

```
package com.example.socialnetwork.socialnetwork;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class FindFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;

private ImageButton SearchButton;
private EditText SearchInputText;

private RecyclerView SearchResultList;

private DatabaseReference allUsersDatabaseRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_friends);


    allUsersDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_appbar_layout);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Find Friends");

    SearchResultList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);
    SearchResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    SearchResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    SearchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_people_friends_button);
    SearchInputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box_input);


    SearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String searchBoxInput = SearchInputText.getText().toString();

            SearchPeopleAndFriends(searchBoxInput);
        }
    });
}


private void SearchPeopleAndFriends(String searchBoxInput)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Searching....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Query searchPeopleandFriendsQuery = allUsersDatabaseRef.orderByChild("fullname")
            .startAt(searchBoxInput).endAt(searchBoxInput + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FindFriends, FindFriendsViewHolder>
            (
                    FindFriends.class,
                    R.layout.all_users_display_layout,
                    FindFriendsViewHolder.class,
                    searchPeopleandFriendsQuery
            )
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FindFriendsViewHolder viewHolder, FindFriends model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setFullName(model.getFullname());
            viewHolder.setStatus(model.getStatus());
            viewHolder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfileimage());
        }
    };
    SearchResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}



public static class FindFriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View mView;

    public FindFriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = mView;
    }


    public void setProfileimage(Context ctx, String profileimage) {

        CircleImageView myImage = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(profileimage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(myImage);
    }


    public void setFullName(String fullname) {

        TextView myName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_profile_full_name);
        myName.setText(fullname);
    }


    public void setStatus(String status) {

        TextView myStatus = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.all_users_status);
        myStatus.setText(status);
    }
}
```

}

Now I'm copying the error message I receive when I search a name in find friends after I run the app. App stops working and goes back to main.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.socialnetwork.socialvegan, PID: 9563
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.socialnetwork.socialnetwork.FindFriendsActivity$FindFriendsViewHolder.setFullName(FindFriendsActivity.java:118)
>                         at com.example.socialnetwork.socialnetwork.FindFriendsActivity$2.populateViewHolder(FindFriendsActivity.java:88)
>                         at com.example.socialnetwork.socialnetwork.FindFriendsActivity$2.populateViewHolder(FindFriendsActivity.java:84)
>                         at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:165)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1767)
>                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:356)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
>                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9563 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

Perhaps someone can find a fix to this. All the build.gradle looks fine. I don't see any mistake. I'm new to the firebase database. There may be a mistake with querying firebase database.

Comment: make sure mView is not null (line : 118)

Comment: Thanks. I missed that =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mView is `null`.  That's because this line of code in `FindFriendsViewHolder` does nothing:

```
mView = mView;
```

mView starts `null` and remains `null` forever, because it's never set with a non-null value.

It looks like you want to use [itemView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#itemView) from ViewHolder instead.

Comment: Thanks bro. I don't know how I missed that =D